# Django reverse lookup of a OneToOneField from a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, database, django

I'm trying to access specific fields via a rather convoluted lookup in Django. I want to search a ManyToManyField Tags, which links to a Poem model, which in turn is linked to by a UserPoem model with a OneToOneField. I just can't work out how to do it:

```
class Poem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    thetext = models.TextField()

class UserPoem(models.Model):
    poem = models.OneToOneField(Poem, related_name='u_poem')
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    poems = models.ManyToManyField(Poem)`
```

So given a tag, I want to get information involving the text of title of the poems in that tag and also the user, date of the poem etc. I've tried various methods involving select_related, but just can't crack it. Here is the (not working) tags request:

```
def tag_page(request, tag_name):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, name=tag_name)
    poems = tag.poems.order_by('-id').select_related('u_poem')
```

I'm just really confused by the way that Django's relationships work. I've had untold problems every since I decided to split the Poems table model in two.

This doesn't return an error; it just doesn't seem to return any information from the UserPoem / u_poem table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your place I would do :

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

class Poem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    thetext = models.TextField()
    tags   = models.ManyToManyField(Poem)
```

so :

```
def tag_page(request, tag_name):
    poems_sets = []
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, name=tag_name)
    poems = Poem.objects.filter(tags__name=tag).order_by('-id')             
    for p in poems:                
        usersp = UserPoem.objects.filter(poem=p)
        for u in usersp:
            poems_sets.append((p, u))
    return locals()
```

template :

```
{% for poem,usersp in poems_sets %}
    {{poem.title}}
    {{poem.thetext}}
    {% for u in usersp %}
        {{u.date}}
        {{u.user}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi. I see where you're coming from but it doesn't really solve my problem. Not only does it mess up other parts of my application (when I use _set), but I still can't see how to access the userpoems table with that change.

Comment: In other places I used `poem.tag_set` and similar queries. Also, is a for loop the only way to do this? I guess I was thinking of more 'elegant solutions' and maybe that's why I struggled so much with this. Many thanks regardless.

Comment: Hi astro - I've added your code to my app and the webpage just displays nothing at all. The poems_sets array is empty.

Comment: are you sure there is such data? is poems and usersp aren't empty?

Comment: Yes. It seems that Poem.objects.filter(tags__name=tag).order_by('-id')  returns nothing...

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say that there are already plenty of poems and tags in the database. I've changed `Poem.objects.filter(tags__name=tag).order_by('-id')` to `Poem.objects.filter(tags__name=tag_name).order_by('-id')` and now it's complaining that the UserPoem object is not iterable.

Comment: what does usersp returns?

Comment: Okay, finally got it working. add `values()` to `usersp = UserPoem.objects.filter(poem=p).values()`, and removed the embedded for loop in the template page. Now it's displaying correctly! Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Wait... there's one last infuriating thing.  In the template, `{{u.date}}` returns the date correctly. But `{{u.user}}` returns nothing. I assume this is because the user is a foreign key, so when the UserPoem table is added to the poems_sets it no longer works. What can I do about this? Really confused.

Comment: usersp looks like this: `[{'poem_id': 8, 'date': datetime.date(2013, 10, 22), 'user_id': 1, u'id': 8}] `

Comment: with the edits yu made you can't use the same code for the template!

Comment: you dont have one object userpeom you have several variables, sotry : `{% for poem,date,user_id,id in poems_sets %}
    {{poem.title}}
    {{poem.thetext}}
     {{date}}
     {{user_id}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %} `

Comment: All sorted now. Thanks once more!